# Show highest score and name from list associated with that score

Tags: python, list, for-loop

As my program goes through the for loop, I need the final prompt to include the name of the student with the highest average so far and show that average. As my code is now it shows the highest average so far, but the name of the student keeps changing. How do I get the highest average to stay associated with the appropriate name from the list?

```
students = ["Kenny", "Irvin", "Ezra", "Joe"] 

highest = []
for student in students: 
    print(student, ", input your 3 grades:")
    D = int(input("Discussion: "))
    Q = int(input("Quiz: "))
    A = int(input("Assignment: "))
    wg1 = D * (.20) 
    wg2 = Q * (.30) 
    wg3 = A * (.50) 
    WeightGrade = wg1 + wg2 + wg3 
    highest.append(WeightGrade)
    print("The average grade for " ,student, " is:", WeightGrade)
    print('\n')
    
    max_highest = max(highest)
    if highest is None:
        print("nothing")
    else:
        print("The student with the highest grade is:" ,student, "with a"\
          ,max_highest, "average.")
        print('\n')
```

Comment: If I asked you for the highest of four numbers, would you tell me the highest every time I gave you a number, or would you wait for me to give you all four before calculating the maximum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a dictionary that stores the name of the student with the highest average.

I used a max function with two parameters, the averages dict and it checks the max of the keys (which are the averages of the students).

```
students = ["Kenny", "Irvin", "Ezra", "Joe"] 

averages = {}
for student in students: 
    print(student, ", input your 3 grades:")
    D = int(input("Discussion: "))
    Q = int(input("Quiz: "))
    A = int(input("Assignment: "))
    wg1 = D * (.20) 
    wg2 = Q * (.30) 
    wg3 = A * (.50) 
    WeightGrade = wg1 + wg2 + wg3

    averages[student] = WeightGrade
    
    print("The average grade for " ,student, " is:", WeightGrade)
    print('\n')

    best_student = max(averages, key=averages.get)

    if averages is None:
        print("nothing")
    else:
        print("The student with the averages grade is:" ,best_student, "with a"\
          ,averages[best_student], "average.")
        print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your list's name from `highest` to `grades` -- it has *all* the grades, not just the highest one!  Then change:

```
highest.append(WeightGrade)
```

to:

```
grades.append((WeightGrade, student))
```

Now `grades` is a list of `(grade, student)` tuples.  That means you can do:

```
highest_grade, best_student = max(grades)
print(f"The student with the highest grade is: {best_student} with a {highest_grade} average.\n")
```

Note that it is not possible for `max` to return `None` in this situation, so a check like `if highest is None:` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First, your variable names should reflect what the variable represents. In this case, `highest` is a bad name because that list contains *all* grades, so just call it `grades`.

Next, to find the maximum of N numbers, you don't calculate the maximum every time you are given a new number! Instead, you want until you have all of them before calculating the max, so do that -- in the loop, just append `WeightGrade` to `grades`.

```
students = ["Kenny", "Irvin", "Ezra", "Joe"] 

grades = []
for student in students: 
    print(student, ", input your 3 grades:")
    D = int(input("Discussion: "))
    Q = int(input("Quiz: "))
    A = int(input("Assignment: "))
    wg1 = D * (.20) 
    wg2 = Q * (.30) 
    wg3 = A * (.50) 
    WeightGrade = wg1 + wg2 + wg3 
    grades.append(WeightGrade)
    print("The average grade for " ,student, " is:", WeightGrade)
    print('\n')
```

Then, *outside* the loop, find the `max()` and which students have that grade:

```
highest = max(grades)
print("The maximum grade is ", highest)
print("The following students achieved this grade: ")
for student, grade in zip(students, grades):
    if highest == grade:
        print(student)
```

By having a separate loop that checks if a student's grade is equal to `highest`, you cover the case where multiple students have achieved the highest grade.